# C# preprocessor warning if will cause compile error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity I want to  wrap my class in a #if UNITY_EDITOR. I can still access that class from other scripts without the if statement causing errors and no warning to other programmers until build compilation.

Example:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor
public class ObservableEditor : Editor
{
    //Code here
}
#endif
```

```
public class AnotherClass
{
   public AnotherClass()
   {
        //Call ObservableEditor Observables
        //causes error if not in unity editor programmer is unaware until build
   }
}
```

Is there a good way to throw a warning to other programmers so they know to use the preprocessor?

Comment: what are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: @DanielA.White I want to warn other programmers of potential errors at compilation if pre-processor is not applied.

Comment: What you have will throw a compile-time error.  What more could you possibly do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to issue a warning for when this happens, but C# does have a very neat attribute that may a accomplish what you want. The [Conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute makes so the class/method is only compiled when the provided pre-processor is defined, but if the class/method is called somewhere else it won't throw any errors, even it the pre-processor is not defined

I think that if you use it like this it will work:

```
 using UnityEditor
    
 [System.Diagnostics.Conditional("UNITY_EDITOR")]
 public class ObservableEditor : Editor
 {
     //Code here
 }
```

The only problem is that the programmer will still be unaware that the class/method is only present in the editor, but there are other ways to communicate that, like putting the class in an editor namespace and in an editor [assembly definition](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) so that unity will give an error even while in the editor

Comment: Ill do that and put it inside of the summary thank you for your time <3